# Flutter widget show on all screen

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have music list screen and when press to play the music, the small music player is show at the end of the screen. If click or scroll up, full screen music player will show. User can click button to collapsed the full screen music player. I am using sliding_up_panel plugin to achieve this.

So my question is that I want to show the small music player on every screen in the app if music is playing.

May I know how where to put SlidingUpPanel?

Regards,
Alex[image]

Answer (score 0):

It will need to go in or above or in your router. You could put it in a [Stack widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), where one layer is your player widget and the other is your routed view.

Comment: Like I said I achieved using sliding_up_panel plugin and need to put every screen that want to show the player. My question is that I want to show the player on every screen and I don't what to put that widget in every screen. I want to put the player on main widget and just want to change the content something like that.

Comment: Where are you changing your views/where's your view router?  If you have a single top-level `Scaffold` widget for your app and are routing at 'body:', you could look at using the Scaffold's `bottomSheet:`. This will do what you're describing. However, if you have multiple Scaffolds() and your router swapping Scaffolds() for each of your views, you could put a `Stack()` with your player on top and your routed views on the bottom.  Wherever you're doing your view routing, your player just needs to be somewhere above that in the widget tree.

Comment: (not sure why I can't edit my comment above) ...*Scaffold's `bottomSheet:` for your sliding_up_panel ... *with your sliding_up_panel player on top...

Comment: Hi Pat9RB, thank for your comment. I will try and let you know the solution.